# Certain queries regarding Firebase App indexing

Tags: android, deep-linking, google-app-indexing, firebase-app-indexing

As I'm planning to integrate firebase app indexing for my android app, I am just concern about certain queries :

1. Is firebase app indexing is HIPAA compliance?
2. I don't have a website,So is it possible to have app indexing without having a website?
3. **How to make occur in google search, since I am able to integrate App indexing and checked through ADB bridge/terminal but am not sure how will it occur in google search results**
4. Few guides suggests in order to have app indexing work , prerequisite is to have deep linking. Is that the case? what if I dont have deep linking, can't I use this feature in particular.

Any links, guides , information or insight will be of great help.Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My recommendation is to go to this site:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app

As for your Q's

- 1. Sorry, don't know :) Not a lawyer!
- 2. Yes, on Android, when using the App Indexing SDK, you can submit app content to the search engine.
- 3. Read through: https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-indexing/android/app
- 4. Deep Linking is used to map web content (with a URL) to app content (within an activity, with parameters) so if you are having Google crawl your site, but want to link that to your app, you need to define how they are related...and that's Deep Linking